# Can I temporarily supress the 'Copy Paste' dialog on iPad for a taphold event? (phonegap / jquery mobile)

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a screen in my app where I would like users to have to taphold a div instead of just tap.

The only problem is that about every third time, the copy/paste ipad dialog pops up... this is annoying and if I cannot stop it, I will have to come up with a different solution.

But I would really like to just turn that iPad option off, but just while on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I found out you have to disable right-clicking.

```
$(function(){

    document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

    $(document).mousedown(function(e){

        if ( e.button == 2 )
        { 
            alert('Right mouse button!'); 
            return false; 
        }

        return true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this isn't possible since I received no answers yet... I just changed the event to swipe as opposed to tapHold which works just as good for me.